# Convert column to datetime, wrong format

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, datetime-format

It may be easy to solve, but I am not able to convert a column into a date time. I checked and the format seems right but it does not work

For example,
**132550.013906** should be **13:25:50.013906**

My df:
|          | Time|
| -------- | -------------- |
| 0| 132550.000000|
| 1| 132550.013906|
| 2| 132550.027219|
| 3| 132550.039719|
| 4| 132550.044623|
| 5| 132550.058625|
My code :

```
df['Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format = "%H%M%S.%f" ).map(lambda x: x.time())
```

print(df["Time"][0])
132550.0

```
ValueError: time data '132550' does not match format '%H%M%S.%f' (match)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed the `.` in the time. It's `132550` instead of `132550.XY...`

You can change the format to `%H%M%S` if needed

Comment: Right, the `.` was not supposed to be there, thanks !  `%H%M%S%f` does the work

Comment: No problem. If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted answer for others :)